# redirectmatch without parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

The url
www.ex.com/product_info.php?products_id=23&osCsid=1ed12

should be redirect to www.ex.com/pagex.htm

I've tried the .htaccess with

"`RedirectMatch 301 ."star"product_info.php"star"` https://ex.com/pagex.htm"
(where "star" = *)

but then the parameters are being forwarded to, so 
https://ex.com/pagex.htm?products_id=23&osCsid=1ed12

How to get rid of "?" and everything on parameter stuff?

Answer (score 2):

`RedirectMatch` directive doesn't remove query string. Use `mod_rewrite` based rules as this one:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?product_info\.php$ https://ex.com/pagex.htm? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Trailing `?` strips off any existing query string in target URL.

Comment: Thank you! It works for me.
Adding "?" to the end of target URL in RedirectMatch also eliminates parameters, but leaves "?" sign in the end. So RewriteRule is the right solution